# CNAME is causing redirect error?

Tags: dns, cname

I recently deployed a website hosted with Node.js. I then created a CNAME record for my website, and it is saying that my website is down, because of the page redirecting too many times. I'm using Cloudflare for my DNS, and the CNAME record was "www" for "https://example.com/" on www.example2.com

Comment: We would need more information of what your DNS setting are and how you are redirecting your site.

Comment: @closetnoc Can you please specify what information you need?

Comment: We would need your DNS settings and your redirect code to see what is going on. Cheers!!

Comment: It is a common misconception that DNS CNAMEs redirect.  They don't.   All a CNAME entry in DNS does is point the domain name to the same IP address as another site.     The web server will start to receive requests for both domain names and it must be configured to handle them.  This usually involves setting up virtual host configurations for each domain in the web server.

Answer (score 1):

Without the redirect code to review I would guess that this is a server side issue rather than a DNS issue per-sey. It sounds like a redirect loop has occured where trying to access the default URL is redirecting to an alternate URL that is then redirecting back to the default URL...

IE: www.domain.com is redirecting to www.domain.com/page-1 and www.domain.com/page-1 is redirecting to www.domain.com or something similar to that. This can also be an issue across sites if your site redirects to another site that is redirecting back again.

If you are using Google Chrome you can open the Chrome inspector window (network tab) and in the network tab there is a button with a big circle. If you click on this button then it will preserve the log upon navigation. Then refresh the page and it doesn't matter how many redirects are done you will be able to see the record of it in the network log which will tell you what redirects are being done which will also indicate for you where to look to fix it.